# Create Navigation Drawer using an existing ListView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, listactivity

I'm creating an android application and I have an activity that shows a list of items (listView) taken from a database. I decided to change the application so that the listView is shown in a navigation drawer in the main activity instead of a separate activity, and I don't know how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the activity that displays the listView:

```
public class AddressBook extends ListActivity {
public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
private ListView contactListView;
private CursorAdapter contactAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   contactListView = getListView();
   contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewContactListener);      

   String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
   int[] to = new int[] { R.id.contactTextView };
   contactAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
      AddressBook.this, R.layout.contact_list_item, null, from, to);
   setListAdapter(contactAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
   super.onResume();

    new GetContactsTask().execute((Object[]) null);
 }

@Override
protected void onStop() 
{
   Cursor cursor = contactAdapter.getCursor();

   if (cursor != null) 
      cursor.deactivate();

  contactAdapter.changeCursor(null);
  super.onStop();
 }

private class GetContactsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
{
   DatabaseConnector databaseConnector = 
      new DatabaseConnector(AddressBook.this);

  @Override
  protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
  {
     databaseConnector.open();

     return databaseConnector.getAllContacts(); 
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
  {
     contactAdapter.changeCursor(result);
     databaseConnector.close();
  }
}

OnItemClickListener viewContactListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) 
  {

     Intent viewContact = 
        new Intent(AddressBook.this, ViewContact.class);

     viewContact.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
     startActivity(viewContact);
  }
};
}
```

And here is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="8dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
```

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @DavidJhons Thank you, this was very helpful. It took me a while trying to change it so that it meets my requirements, but I couldn't have done it without that link. You can post that as an answer if you want so that I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks again.